# Name mixup on photo of the week

Tags: discussion, support, bug, status-completed, featured-photo

I notice that the photo of the week has my name attached. I didn't take this image. I didn't enter the "Death" competition. I believe the person who took this is dmkonlinux... Please correct the name and link (which connects to the Manipulation competition, not the Death competition).

Answer (score 3):

Crap. My sincerest apologies to both you and [dmkonlinux](https://photo.stackexchange.com/users/60903/dmkonlinux) on the mixup.

Logging the Hall of Fame winners is a completely manual process, lots of copy/pasting. I was probably moving too fast, and forgot to double-check all of the links and information as I was going.

I've fixed the Hall of Fame link & attribution info, and updated the PotW sidebar.

Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thanks! I know you guys work your butts off dealing with various things, so thanks for that as well...

Comment: thanks all for the correction

Comment: @dmkonlinux absolutely no problem. Again, sorry for the misattribution.